# why is jest v24 mocking class requiring private methods

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I need to create a mock implementations of my typescript classes using jest v24+. I am specifically trying to create a mock class that gets injected into a constructor and mock the function(s) that will be called to return a specific response.

How do I create a mock for each test?

More info:

I have started a new project and am now using jest v24, which has created a problem with writing tests that I have been unable to solve.

Using the below example with jest v23, previously I could mock the Randomiser class as follows:

```
const Mock = jest.fn<Randomiser>(() => ({
  getRandom: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(10)
}));
```

which would successfully compile and build.

As of v24 the fn function takes and addition generic `<T, Y extends any[]>` I don't know if this is relevant to change in behaviour but now I get an error:

*Property 'rand' is missing in type '{ getRandom: Mock; }' but required in type 'Randomiser'.ts(2741)*

```
import "jest";

class Randomiser {
    public getRandom(): number {
        return this.rand();
    }
    private rand(): number {
        return Math.random();
    }
}

class Multiplier {
    private randomiser: Randomiser;
    constructor(randomiser: Randomiser) {
        this.randomiser = randomiser;
    }

    multiplyRandom(factor: number): number {
        return Math.floor(this.randomiser.getRandom() * factor);
    }
}

describe("tests", () => {
    it("10 x 2 = 20", () => {
        const Mock = jest.fn<Randomiser, any>(() => ({
            getRandom: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(10),
            rand: jest.fn() //with this line I get an error because it should be private, without this line I get the error above.
        }));
        expect(new Multiplier(new Mock()).multiplyRandom(2)).toBe(20);
    })
})
```

I was expecting to be able to write my mocks the same way as I was with v23, i.e. I could mock the class and only need to mock the functions I was going to call.

Now I have to mock all the functions including the private functions and private properties which it then complains are not private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions:

**1. Use `Partial<Type>`, which will allow you to partially mock your class:**

```
const Mock = jest.fn<Partial<Randomiser>, []>(() => ({
  getRandom: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(10)
}));
```

Then cast your mock to your class type to inject it, for example:

```
const mock: Randomiser = new Mock() as Randomiser;
expect(new Multiplier(mock).multiplyRandom(2)).toBe(20);
```

**2. Don't specify any type for the mock.**

Another way is to not specify the type for the mock, which makes the mock type `any`.

```
const Mock = jest.fn(() => ({
  getRandom: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(10)
}));
```

Then you can inject your mock as is directly, but of course, it will not be typed in this case.

```
const mock = new Mock();
expect(new Multiplier(mock).multiplyRandom(2)).toBe(20);
```

Comment: Thank you, since jest 24, I wasn't able to mock a class partially and I didn't know about the Partial one, thank you!